# Is there an equivalent listener on WSO2 to Mule's http-listener-connector

Tags: http, wso2, esb

Mule ESB has an [HTTP Listener Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector) that accepts all types of HTTP calls. I am trying to migrate a project from Mule to WSO2. I couldn't find how to create a similar listener on WSO2. Does a similar feature exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/HTTP+Endpoint) is a similar construct.

Comment: And, WSO2 ESB supports much more connector. You can visit [WSO2 Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/) and see other connector as well.